# submit form with checkbox 2 values

Tags: php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I am a newbie and I have tried multiple ways with no luck.

I am retrieving productName, productID, and productLink from my database.

I have a form based on checkbox. I want to be able to pass only the data of the checked box. I want to POST the productId and the productLink of the checked box.

Right now when I submit, I get the productId of the checked product but I get all the product Links. How do I make it so I only get the product link of the checked box.

```
    <form action="process.php" method="post">
   <table>
   <tr> 
   <td> <input type="checkbox" name="productId[]" value="<?php echo $products->id; ?>" /> <input type="hidden" name="productLink[]" value="<?php echo $products->link; ?>" /> Product Name Goes Here</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td> <input type="checkbox" name="productId[]" value="<?php echo $products->id; ?>" /> <input type="hidden" name="productLink[]" value="<?php echo $products->link; ?>" />  Product Name Goes Here</td>
    </tr>
    <td> <input type="checkbox" name="productId[]" value="<?php echo $products->id; ?>" /> <input type="hidden" name="productLink[]" value="<?php echo $products->link; ?>" /> Product Name Goes Here</td>
    <tr>
    <td> <input type="checkbox" name="productId[]" value="<?php echo $products->id; ?>" /> <input type="hidden" name="productLink[]" value="<?php echo $products->link; ?>" /> Product Name Goes Here</td>
    </tr>
    <td> <input type="checkbox" name="productId[]" value="<?php echo $products->id; ?>" /> <input type="hidden" name="productLink[]" value="<?php echo $products->link; ?>" /> Product Name Goes Here</td>
    <tr>
    <td> <input type="checkbox" name="productId[]" value="<?php echo $products->id; ?>" /> <input type="hidden" name="productLink[]" value="<?php echo $products->link; ?>" /> Product Name Goes Here</td>
    <td> <input type="checkbox" name="productId[]" value="<?php echo $products->id; ?>" /> <input type="hidden" name="productLink[]" value="<?php echo $products->link; ?>" /> Product Name Goes Here</td>
    </tr>

    </table>
    <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit" />

    </form>
```

---

Here is the array I am now getting.

```
    Array
    (

    [productId] => Array
    (
    [400] => link.html
    [399] => link.html
    )

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using an array as the variable you're passing, make the array do the work for you:

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" 
           name="productId[<?= $products->id ?>]" 
           value="<?= $products->link ?>" /> Product Name Goes Here 
</label>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. That really helped me out! Got it working.